# GetStateByPartialCompositeKey not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, composite-primary-key, smartcontracts

I have a problem with the method "GetStateByPartialCompositeKey". They index consists of 5 parts (key1~key2~key3~key4~key5)
If i try GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(index, key1), it works perfectly. If I try to search for another key, like GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(index, key3), nothing is returned. Although the key is actually saved.
Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that you should also provide keys that are preceding the key you want to query by. That means if you want to query by key3 in your case, you should also provide key1 and key2 to call

```
GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(objectType string, keys []string) (StateQueryIteratorInterface, error)
```

Since there's no preceding keys before key1, you can do the query by providing key1 only. If you want to query by key3, then you should do it like below

```
GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(index, []string{key1, key2, key3})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But what if I do not care about key1 and key2? Can I use any wildcard? I mean I want to search for the key3 only actually. Any way to realize that?

Comment: Sadly there's no way to realize that